# How to turn a message into a string with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to take a string from a client.on('message') and turn it into a variable?

Comment: As asked, this question doesn't make any kind of sense. Variables can point to literally anything, so the obvious answer here is just the three letter answer "yes". That is obviously not the answer you're looking for, so what do you actually want to know? And can you please edit your post to reflect that?

Comment: I think that you should learn the basics of Javascript before trying to make a discord bot. If your question is *How to get the content if the message*, you can do like so: ``message.content``. C.f: 
[The doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question. I tried to answer it, but what would you like to turn into a variable?

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  // the message variable is an Object.
  // see: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable through the message event listener by the following:

```
client.on("message", message => {
    // Code
}
```

Your variable will automatically be converted to a string by Discord.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this easily,

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
})
```

`message` is automatically a variable.
This means you can do things like this:

```
if (message.content === "test") {
message.channel.send("tube")
}
```

You can see [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) for more information.

Comment: Note: this was a small example of what you can do with ``client.on('message', (message)``
If you are starting out i recommend a couple discord.js tutorials on youtube.